# Update image of a button depending on its previous image

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I am trying to program a start/pause button in Tkinter (Python) but the following code doesn't work:

```
def startpause():
 if startpause_button.cget('image')=='start_image':
  startpause_button.config(image=pause_image)
 else:
  startpause_button.config(image=start_image)
return

start_image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='start.png')
pause_image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='pause.png')
   
startpause_button=ttk.Button(frame,image=start_image,command = startpause)
```

I understand the issue is about cget (which return ('pyimage3'), ) and what it returns but I don't know what to put as a value to check ("('pyimage3')," doesn't work).

Do you have any idea about this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Try comparing it to your `start_image` and not the string `'start_image'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`startpause_button.cget('image')` and `'start_image'` are two different things, `.cget('image')` returns the name of the image in a list e.g. `('pyimage1',)`. This means to compare them you need to take it out of the list with `[0]` and make sure both variables are strings with `str()` because `'pyimage1'` and `pyimage1` are also two different things

```
import tkinter.ttk
from tkinter import Tk, PhotoImage

def startpause():
    global start_image
    if str(startpause_button.cget('image')[0])==str(start_image):
        startpause_button.config(image=pause_image)
    else:
        startpause_button.config(image=start_image)
    #return # i dont think you need this

global start_image
start_image=PhotoImage(file='start.gif')
pause_image=PhotoImage(file='pause.gif')

startpause_button=tkinter.ttk.Button(frame,image=start_image,command = startpause)
```

This does work and I've tested it, hope this helps you! :)